# Rails text field stored in DB with "\n" when output in ERB template not formatting right

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the snippet below in an ERB template:

```
<% @task.notes.each do |note| %>
  <%= note.description %>
<% end %>
```

The text in one of the note's description is:

`reply \n\nHello`

But when it's output in the ERB template, it disregards the `\n` in the text.

Adding `.html_safe` to it does nothing.

How can I have it output with the `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper.

From the documentation:

> Returns text transformed into HTML using simple formatting rules. Two
>   or more consecutive newlines(`\n\n`) are considered as a paragraph and
>   wrapped in `<p>` tags. One newline (`\n`) is considered as a linebreak and
>   a `<br />` tag is appended. This method does not remove the newlines
>   from the text.

Does exactly what you want with no extra fuss.